# cartography of an network

Tags: networking, snmp, pysnmp, snmp4j

I want to realize a program that would look in the MIB of a Cisco equipment.

I have done research on the SNMP protocol (so I know that the equipment has what is called the agent or the server so I need a manager / client), OID, but I block enough on The program (a kind of batch to do in my opinion) to make the communication with the switch. And how to find the corresponding OIDs.

So the idea is to do a mapping of a network (cisco) from
Of a central node and browse all the equipments, all this is based only on two protocols CDP (for the neighbors) and snmp
For the interrogation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems you just described your project but did not ask a question.

Comment: I can not find a library C to query the cisco equipment and to subfile the information of the necessary OID in a file !!!

Comment: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Comment: you want a question , okay,How I can recover the MIB of a router and specially a specific OID (like ip address of each interface) in a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `CISCO-CDP-MIB` that contains all the information for topology discovery. This MIB has `cdpCacheAddress` and `cdpCacheDevicePort` tables that hold switch/router neighbors. So that is your starting point.

Comment: Thank you my friend but I found the problem how to restore the results in a file?knowing that I use the net-snmp library and pdu type variables so I want the data returned in this last variable puts into a file! i wish That you understand my idea

Comment: Simply redirect console output to a file.